# When are the variables allocated and initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector, constructor

Please take a look at this code:

```
template <typename T>
class matrix
{
    private:
        std::vector<T> vec_;

public:
    matrix(size_t rows , size_t cols) : rows_(rows) , cols_(cols) , vec_(rows_ * cols_)
    {
    }       
    size_t rows_;
    size_t cols_;   

};
```

This is a way to declare a class. I am just wondering where the `std::vector` is being allocated and where it is being initialized?

What happens when I declare a variable? Is the space for it allocated in the stack before the constructor is called or is allocated and initialized in the constructor?

What is the difference between declaring a vector with size 10

```
 std::vector<T> vec_(10);
```

and calling the constructor of vec_ with the size 10 in the constructor?

```
 matrix() : vec_(10)
```

I wanted to understand how objects are allocated and initialized in C++.

Also I can create a constructor without calling the constructor of `std::vector`

```
 matrix() {}
```

What is happening here? Since I am not calling the constructor for the vector does the compiler call it own its own? Can the vector object utilized? Or is it called automatically because I declared `std::vector` to be a variable in my class?

Also does initializing as `std::vector vec(10)`, have the same effect as calling resize/reserve. Which is it closer to?

Comment: "This is a way to declare a class" -- no. It's a definition of a **template**; the template is a pattern for defining classes.

Answer (score 2):

that code:

```
private:
    std::vector<T> vec_(10);
```

doesn't compile as Bo noted. But you could do this in a legal & performant way in c++11 (as performant because of [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization?s=1%7C6.2235): assignment operator is very likely to be turned into a copy constructor because object is being initialized at this very line):

```
private:
    std::vector<T> vec = std::vector<T>(10);
```

So, that previous construct and this one:

```
public: 
     matrix() : vec_(10)
```

do the same: `vec_` will be built once, with 10 elements inside it, exactly like `resize` would do, except that it's faster because you don't have to create an empty vector *and* resize it.

For the second part of your question: If you create your instance using a default constructor, the compiler will call the default constructor for all class members, so it is perfectly safe.

Beware: POD objects are not zeroed, which may be a problem, so it's better to set pointers to `nullptr`, integers to 0, etc... or you get uninitialized values, not good when entering the destructor with an invalid pointer passed to `delete` ...

Of course, it will fail to compile if one of the members has only non-default constructors (needing a parameter).

Comment: If I call push_back on vec_ that will be the 11th item then right ?

Comment: absolutely. This is like `resize`, not `reserve`

Comment: So If I write a constructor which only calls the constructor for some of the members  and not the others, the compiler will automatically call the cstor for the ones I did not call it for ?

Comment: yes, all members that you don't explicitly "build" will be built using the default constructor if there is one (else it won't compile)

Answer (score 2):

The members of a class object are initialized in the order they are declared. In this case it is this order:

```
private:
    std::vector<T> vec_;

public:
   size_t rows_;
   size_t cols_;
```

so when executing the initializer list

```
matrix(size_t rows , size_t cols) : rows_(rows) , cols_(cols) , vec_(rows_ * cols_)
```

the *real* order is

```
vec_(rows_ * cols_), rows_(rows) , cols_(cols)
```

which is using `rows_` and `cols_` before they are initialized. And bad things will happen.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you !

Comment: doesn't really answer the question, but very nice remark. Note that g++ warns you about that.

Comment: @jean - The question was expanded while I wrote my answer. I'll try to add more info on that.

Comment: @BoPersson don't do that for me you already have my upvote :)

Comment: @jean - Ok, I'll pass on that because `std::vector<T> vec_(10);` is not allowed (syntax error), and `std::vector<T> vec_{10};` will have different meaning depending on which version of `initializer_list` your compiler is using.

Comment: doesn't compile, you're right. I have edited my answer, and successfully found a way to fall on my feet :)